# pdf book reader in php using fpdf library

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fpdf

I want to develop a feature to read uploaded pdf file in a browser as a book format.
Can anyone suggest me how can we achieve this?
I am trying to achieve it using php, jquery of javascript.

Comment: Have you even read what FPDF does?

Comment: Yes, here i am looking for solution to achieve that. If there is any other library or tool exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of JS on following link
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Usage example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- In production, only one script (pdf.js) is necessary -->
  <!-- In production, change the content of PDFJS.workerSrc below -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/shared/util.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/shared/colorspace.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/shared/pattern.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/shared/function.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/shared/annotation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/display/api.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/display/metadata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/display/canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/display/font_loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Specify the main script used to create a new PDF.JS web worker.
    // In production, leave this undefined or change it to point to the
    // combined `pdf.worker.js` file.
    PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../src/worker_loader.js';
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
</body>

</html>
```

hello.js - file

```
//
// Fetch the PDF document from the URL using promises
//
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
  // Using promise to fetch the page
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    //
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    //
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    //
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
  });
});
```

This will help you provide direct view of the attachment

Answer (score 1):

I have trying to develop PDF book using https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js but no luck.

I am not sure what parameters I will change in the "viewer.js" file in order make PDF book. I am refraining https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website-%28Windows%29 documation. I am able to open PDF in the browser, but not open PDF in book format.

Comment: In view.js you will change the file path that opens the PDF properly, may be you make use of method that calls this code and the function parameter helps to switch in file name as per required, rest the code should remain the same and I see it working. May be give one more chance and you could succeed